# Using flex box how can I meet my design requirements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Using flex box how can I meet my design requirements?

[design requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNQgN.png)

Current code

Current code as you can see I have went down the flex box path to achieve my design requirement However, this code output doesn't match my design requirements screenshot and I was wondering how I can achieve this.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 200px); /* 200px is width of 2 boxes */
  }
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Current output based on the code above.
[flex output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KhfE.png)

Comment: Right alignment and then left on the next row is not really something flexbox can do. You might be better using Css-grid

Comment: Sure, how could I use css grid to achieve this result? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your picture example i have constructed the design.Some of the classes have introduced and HTML have also been changed.if you think This workaround can help you you can accept it.else feel free to comment.

HTML CODE below

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="firstSection">
        <div class="item item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="secondSection">
        <div class="item item2"></div>
        <div class="item item3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style

```
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .secondSection {
        display: flex;
    }

    .item {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        display: block;
    }

    .item1 {
        background: red;
    }

    .item2 {
        background: blue;
    }

    .item3 {
        background: green;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
        .container {
            flex-direction: column-reverse;
        }
        .secondSection{
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }
    }
```